# xparse command optional argument in \uline{} error

Tags: errors, expansion, xparse, ulem

Sorry, but I am so bad in English.
I try my best to describe my problem.

Here is an example

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{o m}{
    % #1#2
}
\begin{document}

%\uline{\test[ab]{c d}}  %fine
\uline{\test[a b]{c d}}

\end{document}
```

log:

```
Runaway argument?
\ERROR {c d}\xdef \UL@spfactor {\the \spacefactor } \UL@end *  
./test.tex:60: Paragraph ended before \test  was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.60 
     
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

`\uline{\test[ab]{c d}}` is fine.

but `\uline{\test[a b]{c d}}` raised an error, where the difference between them is the optional argument `[ab]` and `[a b]` (there is a white space between `a` and `b`).

What should I do if I want something like `\uline{\test[a b]{c d}}` to work fine?

thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure why, but `\uline{\test[{a b}]{c d}}` works.

Comment: @Teepeemm thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\uline` starts off its job by splitting its argument at spaces. Those inside *braces* are not taken into account when doing this splitting, but there's no way to exclude from consideration those appearing in *brackets*. This ends up in examining `\test[a` as a single chunk, which will break.

`\test[{a b}]{c d}` should do.

Maybe you've better luck with `lua-ul` (which requires LuaLaTeX).

Comment: Thank you.  `\test[{a b}]{c d}` it works.